# Sharing an entire package/module via multiprocessing manager

Tags: python-multiprocessing

I have a simulator which generates multiple python sub-interpreters. In each, I would like to load the package web3.py, which unfortunately is not fond of sub-interpreters so it throws an error. The solution I am trying to go for currently is to spawn a new process which hosts the web3.py package to the corresponding sub-interpreter.
This is my current coding attempt, but there is a lack of examples which share complex objects such as an web3 instance, so I am stuck. The web3 instance w3 is exported without attributes.

```
import multiprocess as mp
import time

from multiprocess.managers import BaseManager


def worker():
    from web3 import Web3, IPCProvider, WebsocketProvider
    from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware
    print('Process to host web3.py')

    provider = WebsocketProvider('ws://'+'172.18.0.11'+':8545')
    w3 = Web3(provider)
    w3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)
    print(w3.eth.coinbase)

    def x():
        return 5

    # BaseManager.register('x', callable=x)
    BaseManager.register('w3')

    manager = BaseManager(address=('', 50000), authkey=b'abc')
    server = manager.get_server()
    server.serve_forever()

    return

if __name__ == '__main__':

    jobs = []
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    p = mp.Process(target=worker)
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
    time.sleep(2)

    print('test')
    m = BaseManager(address=('127.0.0.1', 50000), authkey=b'abc')
    m.connect()

    # m.register('x')
    # print(m.x())    <------ This works!

    m.register('w3')
    print(m.w3.eth.coinbase)

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you did is on the right line: load modules and create objects on each process, instead of sharing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).